# Sum based on the cell in previsous row and in the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very simple table

| A | R | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 29.90709 |
| 7 | 0.1 | 25.1978 |
| 13 | 0.4 | 17.07692 |
| 4 | 0.2 | 15.69231 |
| 8 | 0.3 | 10 |
| 10 | 0.1 | 0 |

where number 29.90709 is calculated as 7+25.1978/(1+0.1).

My question is how to implement calculation of column B. I know how to do it in Excel, but not in R, since I need the value from the previous cell of column B. Is the any way or a function that can use a reference to a previous calculated cell?

Example data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "A   R   B
0   0   29.90709
7   0.1 25.1978
13  0.4 17.07692
4   0.2 15.69231
8   0.3 10
10  0.1 0", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is `1+0.1` a constant? Where is the 1 coming from?

Comment: Can you clarify how is 10 calculated on ColumnB?

Comment: Formula n-th row is B[n] = A[n-1]+B[n-1]/(1+R[n-1]), where B[0] = 0.

Comment: @zx8754 10 in column B is calculated as 10 + 0/(1+0.1).

Comment: @RitchieSacramento can this bi done directly on the table?, so that result would be in the same table as columns A and R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::accumulate2()` which can operate on two vectors:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(B = rev(head(unlist(purrr::accumulate2(rev(A), rev(R), ~ ..2 + ..1 / (1 + ..3), .init = 0)), -1)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      A     R     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0   0    29.9
2     7   0.1  25.2
3    13   0.4  17.1
4     4   0.2  15.7
5     8   0.3  10  
6    10   0.1   0
```

Or with base `Reduce()` by indexing the vectors:

```
df %>%
  mutate(B = rev(head(Reduce(function(x, y) A[y] + x / (1 + R[y]), rev(seq_along(A)), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE), -1)))
```

Because you want the calculation from the bottom up it might make more sense to reverse the rows of your data frame than each element and the result individually:

```
df %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
  mutate(B = head(Reduce(function(x, y) A[y] + x / (1 + R[y]), seq_along(A), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE), -1)) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *forloop*:

```
x <- vector("numeric", nrow(d))

for(i in (nrow(d) - 1):1){
    x[ i ] <- d$A[i + 1] + x[i + 1] / (1 + d$R[i + 1])   
  }

d$result <- x  
#    A   R        B   result
# 1  0 0.0 29.90709 29.90709
# 2  7 0.1 25.19780 25.19780
# 3 13 0.4 17.07692 17.07692
# 4  4 0.2 15.69231 15.69231
# 5  8 0.3 10.00000 10.00000
# 6 10 0.1  0.00000  0.00000
```